# Valgrind "Invalid write of size 8" error after malloc

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, strtok

So I want to parse a shell-like command and store it on a char** in order to pass it as an argument on the execv system call. In the function below the parsing and storing works correctly.

```c
char ** input_delimit(char *command){            // 19
    char **retval;                               // 20
    const char space[2]=" ";                     // 21
    int i=0;                                     // 22
    retval=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));        // 23
    retval[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));       // 24
    retval[i]=strtok(command,space);             // 25
    while(retval[i]!=NULL){                      // 26
        i++;                                     // 27
        retval[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));   // 28
        retval[i]=strtok(NULL,space);            // 29
    }                                            // 30
    return retval;                               // 31
}                                                // 32
```

When I run my code with Valgrind, I get the following error messages (although it does correctly what I want it to do). Why does this happen?

```
==824== Invalid write of size 8
==824==    at 0x109410: input_delimit (shell.c:28)
==824==    by 0x109493: execute_command (shell.c:35)
==824==    by 0x109600: main (shell.c:64)
==824==  Address 0x4a489d8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==824==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==824==    by 0x1093A7: input_delimit (shell.c:23)
==824==    by 0x109493: execute_command (shell.c:35)
==824==    by 0x109600: main (shell.c:64)
==824==
==824== Invalid write of size 8
==824==    at 0x109439: input_delimit (shell.c:29)
==824==    by 0x109493: execute_command (shell.c:35)
==824==    by 0x109600: main (shell.c:64)
==824==  Address 0x4a489d8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==824==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==824==    by 0x1093A7: input_delimit (shell.c:23)
==824==    by 0x109493: execute_command (shell.c:35)
==824==    by 0x109600: main (shell.c:64)
==824==
==824== Invalid read of size 8
==824==    at 0x109450: input_delimit (shell.c:26)
==824==    by 0x109493: execute_command (shell.c:35)
==824==    by 0x109600: main (shell.c:64)
==824==  Address 0x4a489d8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==824==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==824==    by 0x1093A7: input_delimit (shell.c:23)
==824==    by 0x109493: execute_command (shell.c:35)
==824==    by 0x109600: main (shell.c:64)
```

Comment: One issue other than the main one is that you should remove the extra calls to `malloc`, the results of which you assign to `retval[i]`. You immediately overwrite the results of `malloc` with the results of `strtok`. It seems that this is written with a mix of very low-level and (non-C) high-level memory management styles being merged (allocations are made manually, but seem to be expected to resize themselves automatically).

Comment: `retval=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));` That is an array of one pointer. How many pointers does your code attempt to store?

Comment: You really need to rethink your memory allocations. How much memory are you allocating and for what?

Comment: `retval` has room for exactly one pointer. Reaching line 28 means that you have at least two pointers. That's one too many.

Comment: Note that `sizeof` just returns an integer - the compiler is not checking that the expression given to `sizeof` (which is an operator btw, not a function call) makes sense.  So you can `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocation 1 byte (on most systems) and store that pointer to something like `int *myIntArray` and the compiler won't catch the problem that the array is pointing at only 1 byte when it needs more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
>         retval=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
> ```

... allocates enough space to store *one* `char *`.

This ...

> ```
>         retval[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
> ```

... allocates space for one `char` and assigns a pointer to it to `retval[i]`.  That space is subsequently leaked when you overwrite that pointer with a different one:

> ```
>         retval[i]=strtok(command,space);
> ```

But now comes the main problem.  `retval` points to space large enough for one `char *`.  Therefore, *every* iteration of this ...

> ```
>                 i++;
>                 retval[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
>                 retval[i]=strtok(NULL,space);
> ```

... overruns the bounds of the allocated space (not to mention allocating and immediately leaking another block).  I would expect Valgrind to notice, and to emit exactly such a diagnostic as you describe.

Suggestions:

1. Start out by allocating space for at least *two* blocks, because  you will need at least that for any valid command.
2. Skip those single-`char` allocations. Not only do they serve no useful purpose, they are actually harmful.
3. When you fill up the allocated space without reaching the end of the command, use `realloc()` to obtain space for more words.  This implies that you must keep track of how much space you have already allocated.  Example:

   ```
   char *temp = realloc(retval, new_capacity * sizeof(*retval));
   if (!temp) {
       // handle allocation failure ...
   } else {
       retval = temp;
   }
   ```

Comment: @GiorgosMellios, I take you to be asking about the single-`char` allocations.  They have nothing whatever to do with the behavior of `strtok()` or the disposition of its return value.   It is the space to which `retval` points where the return value of `strtok()` is written.  And that return value, itself a pointer, points into the string being tokenized.  The additional allocations are not used for anything.  They are just allocated and then leaked.  Writing the pointers to them into `retval` serves no useful purpose.

Comment: But isn't it necessary to allocate memory so that ```strtok()``` will write to a "legal" address?
I'm telling that because if i remove malloc at line 24 I get the following assertion: ```malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.```

Comment: Again no, @GiorgosMellios.  The `malloc()` at line 23, if successful, provides the space where the return value of the initial `strtok()` is written.  And also the space where the return value of the needless extra `malloc()` is written.  Nothing is *ever* written at the location of the one-`char` allocations, and those allocations are not large enough for the return value of `strtok` anyway.  The assertion failure you present indicates an error elsewhere -- possibly, but not necessarily, the same one Valgrind warns about, and that I describe in this answer.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot and sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 4):

You dynamically allocated memory only for one pointer

```
   retval=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

So this loop

```
   while(retval[i]!=NULL){
           i++;
           retval[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
           retval[i]=strtok(NULL,space);
   }
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover these statements

```
retval[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
retval[i]=strtok(command,space)
```

produce a memory leak because memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `retval[i]` and in the next statement the pointer was reassigned. So the address of the allocated memory is lost.

You need to use `realloc` for the pointer `retval` within the while loop.